# Capturar ações: Scroll Down and Scroll Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Existe alguma forma em jQuery de capturar os eventos de "ScrollDown" e "ScrollUp"?

Tentei desta maneira:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      // downscroll code
   } else {
      // upscroll code
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Mas nela não captura a função de UP e DOWN e sim o scroll qualquer!

E eu queria que assim que o rolamento de mouse fosse acionado a função fosse executada.

Isso é possível ?

Comment: Samir, já agora, esta resposta era o que procurava?

Answer (score 5):

O código que você colocou faz o que você quer. Não existe nenhuma outra propriedade do evento que seja indicador de direção, tem mesmo que medir.

Se quiser saber especificamente como medir a direção da roda do mouse, aí é possivel tirar das propriedades do `evento` (dê uma olhada aqui: [Como saber a direção do scroll da roda do mouse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25220/129)).

Mas o scroll é mais abrangente é despoletado de outras maneiras e não somente a roda do mouse.

Dê uma olhada aqui para ver o seu código em funcionamento: [jsfiddle.net/ayxqg/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ayxqg/1/)