# Sites que funcionam pelo scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho visto sites que funcionam pelo scroll, onde não é possível redimensiona-lo, ou seja, quando você tenta redimensionar a página com o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scroll não funciona e o site todo é animado pelo scroll também, como este http://quefreen.com.

Gostaria de saber como fazer dessa forma? É alguma função que trava o scroll?

Comment: Creio que o que você quer esteja respondido parcialmente aqui: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25284/capturar-a%C3%A7%C3%B5es-scroll-down-and-scroll-up](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25284/capturar-a%C3%A7%C3%B5es-scroll-down-and-scroll-up) À partir daí, você pode desenvolver outras coisas. Código do outro post: [http://jsfiddle.net/ayxqg/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ayxqg/1/)

Comment: Obrigado, Shura! Acho que era isso mesmo!