# Menu fixo aparecendo quando rolar a página

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse container aí que vai ter um menu dentro e ele é fixo no topo, gostaria de saber como faço para fazer ele aparecer só quando estiver rolando a página para baixo, e sumir quando estiver rolando para cima, eu vi outros exemplo só que ele aparecer só em determinada parte, e eu gostaria de aprender fazer isso independentemente da altura da página em que esteja.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
var menu_aparecer = $('.menu');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    menu_aparecer.slideDown("fast");
  } else {
    menu_aparecer.slideUp("fast");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 800px;
}
.menu {
  height: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #231F20;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">Container do menu</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Temos de guardar as ultimas posições do scroll para comparar, se for maior é porque estamos a ir para baixo, e se for menor estamos a ir para cima. Pode fazer assim:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop || st === 0){
      $('.menu').slideDown("fast");
   } else {
      $('.menu').slideUp("fast");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
body {
 height: 1000px; 
}
.menu {
  height: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #231F20;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">Container do menu</div>
```

Comment: Esse código faz-me lembrar a pergunta do Samir à uns tempos... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25284/129

Comment: Não vi essa @Sergio, mas de facto até podemos (eu e o samir) ter visto a mesma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Answer (score 0):

consegui fazer assim no meu caso deu certo

```
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop || st === 0){
      $('.topo').css('position','relative');
   } else {
      $('.topo').css('position','fixed');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
<style>
.topo{
background-color:red
}
<body>
  
  <healder class:"topo">
    <h1> Menu aqui</h1>
  </healder>
</body>
```