# Como fazer uma imagem ficar "solta" dentro de uma div

Tags: jquery, html, css, imagem, mobile

Preciso deixar uma imagem "solta" dentro de uma `div` no meu site mobile. A `div` tem dimensões fixas mas a imagem é muito maior, por isso, teria que ser algo semelhante ao `iframe`, porém, sem scroll e o usuário poderá mover a imagem livremente com os dedos.

Na verdade, é uma lista de imagens, cada uma usando a mesma `class`.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="box">
   <img src="imagem1" class="dragme" />
</div>
<div class="box">
   <img src="imagem2" class="dragme" />
</div>
<div class="box">
   <img src="imagem3" class="dragme" />
</div>
<div class="box">
   <img src="imagem4" class="dragme" />
</div>
```

Exemplo do efeito: <sup><sub>(clique para ver o GIF animado)</sub></sup>

[image]

Uma observação que pode ser importante: tive que desabilitar o "zoom" do site, por motivos de forças maiores.. nisso, o "pinch" com os dedos acredito que não funcionará, ficando somente com a movimentação básica dos dedos.

Comment: Por favor, publique a imagem aqui, se o tinypic sumir, a pergunta perde um pouco bastante do sentido...

Comment: Tem razão.. pergunta editada.

Comment: da pra fazer essa imagem para de se mexer? fiquei meio tonto lendo essa pergunta kkk

Comment: @RodrigoBorth, acabo de consertar isso :)

Comment: É pra ficar igual o último quadrinho? http://xkcd.com/1110/ (espero que  vocês estejam com tempo)

Comment: @Bacco sim, como o último quadrinho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que precisa é de uma funcionalidade tipo drag.
Deixo em baixo um exemplo que fiz agora para drag em touch e mouse.

**Acerca da posição do touchmove:**

O evento que é passado no eventhandler é diferente para eventos de mouse e de touch. Nos eventos de mouse a posição do ponteiro é obtida pelo `evento.clientX` e `evento.clientY`. No entanto no touch esse evento encontra-se em `evento.touches[0].clientX` e resp. `evento.touches[0].clientY`. Por causa disto tive de acrescentar uma função para normalizar o evento detectando se se trata de um touch ou de um mouse. Podia ter feito via `e.type` mas optei asssim.

(Estou a usar `e.originalEvent` porque o jQuery não disponibiliza a propriedade `touch` no evento. Disponibiliza somente na propriedade `originalEvent` onde ele passa uma referência ao evento original).

Portanto a função para normalizar a posição:

```
function normalizarEvento(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.touches && e.originalEvent.touches.length) return e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    return e;
}
```

Para isso precisa de escutar alguns eventos:

Para inicar o drag:

```
$('img').on('mousedown touchstart', toggleDrag);
```

Para parar oo drag:

```
$('img').on('mouseup touchend mouseout', toggleDrag);
```

A função `toggleDrag` verifica se o tipo de evento é o de iniciar e dá um valor `true` à flag que guarda a informação se o drag está a acontecer.
Esta função guarda ainda a posição do evento em relação à posição da imagem, para poder ter essa informação na outra função quando fôr mover a imagem. Juntei uma função extra para isto tendo em conta a posiçõ relativa na página:

```
function buscarPosicaoRelativa(el) {
    var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: elemRect.left - bodyRect.left,
        y: elemRect.top - bodyRect.top
    }
}
```

A função `drag` muda a `margin` esquerda e topo conforme a posição do mouse.

Seria ainda possivel medir a velocidade do touch para poder mover rápidamente e com efeito de aceleração. Mas isso enquadra-se bem noutra pergunta. E parte dela já respondi aqui: [Como saber a direção do scroll da roda do mouse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25220/129)

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/3t6q1hme/

```
var ondrag = {};
$('.dragme').on('mouseup touchend mouseout', toggleDrag);
$('.dragme').on('mousedown touchstart', toggleDrag);
$('.dragme').on('mousemove touchmove', drag);

function normalizarEvento(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.touches && e.originalEvent.touches.length) return e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    return e;
}

function buscarPosicaoRelativa(el) {
    var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: elemRect.left - bodyRect.left,
        y: elemRect.top - bodyRect.top
    }
}

function toggleDrag(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var moveTouch = normalizarEvento(evt);
    ondrag.on = evt.type == 'mousedown' || evt.type == 'touchstart';
    if (ondrag.on) ondrag.start = {
        x: moveTouch.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y: moveTouch.clientY - this.getBoundingClientRect().top
    };
}

function toggleDrag(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var moveTouch = normalizarEvento(evt);
    var posicaoElemento = buscarPosicaoRelativa(this);
    ondrag.on = evt.type == 'mousedown' || evt.type == 'touchstart';
    if (ondrag.on) ondrag.start = {
        x: moveTouch.clientX - posicaoElemento.x + this.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y: moveTouch.clientY - posicaoElemento.y + this.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().top
    };
}

function drag(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var moveTouch = normalizarEvento(evt);
    if (!ondrag.on) return;
    var x = moveTouch.clientX;
    var y = moveTouch.clientY;
    this.style.marginLeft = x - ondrag.start.x + 'px';
    this.style.marginTop = y - ondrag.start.y + 'px';
}
```

Comment: proponho `onDragon` ou `onDragão` :) Acabo de testar uma variável com acento (`ondragão`) e o fiddle aceitou (¡?)

Comment: Substitui `$('img')` por uma classe específica, e essa classe tem `position:relative`. O efeito não funcionou, tem alguma relação com esse `position`?

Comment: @brasofilo peguei um site que as classes e funções tinham acentos... é engraçado pegar trabalhos assim

Comment: Acredito que não deve ser pelo posicionamento. Não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar. Talvez por que é uma lista de imagens? Todas com uma mesma classe e quando vai "mover" uma delas, dá conflito com as demais?

Comment: @Ricardo pode editar o meu jsFiddle e colocar aqui o código com problemas?

Comment: @Sergio sim, http://jsfiddle.net/z53te9u4/9/ - Nota-se que somente a primeira que você mexe funciona, as demais "buga".

Comment: @Ricardo juntei mais detalhes à resposta e mudei o jsFiddle para a nova versão.

Comment: @brasofilo Sim, em JS quase tudo é válido como identificador.

Comment: @Sergio legal, agora está mais parecido com o que preciso. O único problema é que quando clico primeiro na última, ou na antepenúltima, elas somem!

Comment: @Sergio Testei agora no meu mobile e de fato as imagens estão sumindo ao serem tocadas. Algumas não somem completamente, apenas deslocam para baixo.

Comment: @Ricardo testaste com a versão que está no post? (esta: http://jsfiddle.net/3t6q1hme/) No meu iPdad funciona, posso testar iPhone mais logo.

Comment: @Ricardo testei no iPhone e tablet samsung e o jsFiddle funciona bem. Que plataforma estás a usar?

Comment: @Sergio sério? Bem, pelos testes feitos no Chroms Desktop, dá esse bug. Uso iPhone 5C. Logo farei mais testes e retorno. Obrigado :D

Comment: @Sergio notei que tem dois `function toggleDrag(evt)` e estava dando conflito. Tirei um e funcionou! Obrigado!!

Comment: @Ricardo aha, sorry. Não devia fazer diferênça pois re-declarar uma função faz com que a outra seja sobrescrita, mas sim deve ser assim: http://jsfiddle.net/3t6q1hme/4/