# Back to top button apenas em scroll to top

Tags: jquery

Estou com a seguinte dúvida.
Criei um botão simples para voltar ao topo da página:

```
<a href="page-top" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>  

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var btt = $('.back-to-top');
            btt.on('click', function(e){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop:0
                    }, 500);

                    e.preventDefault();
                });

            $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                var self = $(this),
                    height = self.height(),
                    top = self.scrollTop();

                if(top > height){
                    if(!btt.is('#page-top:visible')){
                        btt.fadeIn();
                        }
                    } else{
                        btt.hide();
                        }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Entretanto gostaria de aplicar o efeito igual ao botão do facebook para mobile, aonde o botão só aparecerá quando eu rolar o scroll pra cima. Tem como?

Answer (score 1):

Dá sim, mas te sugiro que de uma olhada neste plugin:

http://markgoodyear.com/labs/scrollup/?theme=image

Acho que deve te ajudar.

Se não ajudar, explique melhor que botão mobile é esse do facebook...

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Portugues, isto soa mais como um comentário do que resposta, se não possui pontos o suficiente para comentar, procure responder algumas perguntas mais "concretas" e ganhar pontos por exemplo. Assim que tiver pontos poderá comentar.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, dá para fazer de 2 jeitos:

**1- Usando o atributo `delta` do evento de *scroll*:**

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) {
        var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    } else {
        var delta = e.originalEvent.detail * (-40);
    }
    if (delta > 0) {
        // scroll para cima
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        // scroll para baixo
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
```

Obs.:
`DOMMouseScroll` e `e.originalEvent.detail` são para o Firefox. ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMMouseScroll))
`mousewheel` e `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta` são para os outros navegadores. ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel))

**[EDIT]**
Conforme o @Sergio me alertou, a direção do scroll é diferente em browsers diferentes e em SO diferentes. Portanto, deixarei um link [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25220/como-saber-a-dire%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-scroll-da-roda-do-mouse/25221#25221) à uma ótima resposta em relação a isso. Mas a solução 2 continua sendo válida.

**2- Guardando a posição a cada *scroll* e comparando com a anterior:**

```
var lastScroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll < lastScroll){
        // scroll para cima
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        // scroll para baixo
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
    lastScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

**Comparação**

Em questão de performance, não sei te responder, mas acredito que não há grande diferença.
Na solução 1, ambos eventos não são padronizados, por isso devem ser bem testados nos diferentes navegadores.
A solução 2 seria a mais "manual" e talvez a mais óbvia de se pensar.
Para o seu problema, eu usaria a solução 2, que é simples e tem-se a certeza de funcionar em qualquer ambiente.

Comment: Lucas atenção que a direção do scroll é diferente em browsers diferentes. -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25221/129

Comment: Não sabia disso. Vou testar melhor e editar a resposta.